# Highcharter Tooltip and Plotoptions - keyword this

Tags: javascript, r, this, r-highcharter

can anyone help me?

```
highchart() %>%
       hc_add_series(data = mtcars, type = "bar", hcaes(y = mpg)) %>%
       hc_plotOptions(
         series = list(
           #column = list(
             events = list(
               mouseOver = JS("function() { if(this.options.color !== 'red') {this.update({color: 'red'})} }"),
               mouseOut = JS("function() { if(this.options.color === 'red') {this.update({color: '#ddd'})} }")
             )
          # )
         )) %>%
       hc_tooltip(formatter= JS("function () {
                                alert(this.options.color)
                                return this.point.mpg
                                }"))
```

This is the code. It works, but what I want is the get to values of mpg in the mouseover event. 
Desired: `mouseOver = JS("function() { if(this.point.mpg > 10') {this.update({color: 'red'})}`. There is a logic behind the `this` keyword, I don´t understand yet. How can I access they series or point in the `hc_plotOptions` part?

Comment: Can you explain in words what you want to happen when you hover over a given bar with the mouse? Simply writing `hc_tooltip()` without the `formatter`-argument gives you the value of `mpg` for whatever your hovering over. It is not clear what you're trying to do with the colours either.

Comment: The tooltip functions gives me the mpg value - correct. What I desire is the mpg value for the mouseOver event in the hc_plotoptions part.